# Check if PouchDB document is empty

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am working on an application that stores client demographics and health information. My goal is to be able to append something to an existing document and I need to check if a document with a certain ID already exists. I know about the function: `putIfNotExists()` but I need to be able to check this with an `if` statement because I have other conditions.

Isn't there anyway I can check if a document tied to a specific ID exists?

I was trying this:

```
    if (db.get('my_id') !== "") {
        // do something
    }
```

But while this works it also breaks my code because when I try pushing documents based on some user input it executes the above if block when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the best answer but it accomplishes what I want.

I retrieve my document using an id and I check the error status:

```
db.get(id, function(err, resp) {
    if (err) {
        if (err.status == '404') { // if the document does not exist
            // do something
        }
        else {
       // do something else if document exists
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for something that doesn't require you to manually check errors I suggest pouchdb upsert. See here: https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert

Comment: Be careful; `err.status = '404'` will assign the value `'404'` to the error status and always return a truthy value. Also, it's worth making sure that `status` is a string, since `404 !== '404'`.

Perhaps `String(err.status) === '404'` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
db.get('mydoc1', function(err, resp) {
      if (err) {
         console.log("does not exist");
       } else {
        console.log("document exists");
      }
    });
```